# Printing unsigned short values

Tags: c

```
  unsigned short a;
  char temp[] = "70000";
  a = atoi(temp);
  printf("a: %d\n", a);
```

Gives me the output `a: 4464` when it should be `a: 70000` Is there a better way to convert from ASCII to a decimal? The range of a unsigned short is 0 - 65535

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are answering the question yourself. The range of a `unsigned short` is 0-65535, so 70000 doesn't fit into it (2 bytes), use a datatype with 4 bytes instead (`unsigned int` should work, you can check the size with `sizeof`).

Comment: Well this is for my computer science homework and we have to use the data type unsigned short

Comment: @mateo: Well, you can't fit 70000 into 2 bytes, period. If the homework asks you to try, the answer is "I can't and neither can you, teacher". But it propably doesn't, so read again and tell us the exact wording if you want us to answer.

Comment: In this case, you can only store 70000 in two unsigned shorts, but not in one. Sounds weird indeed.

Answer (score 13):

As [schnaader said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134779/printing-unsigned-short-values/5134789#5134789), you may be running into an overflow problem.

But answering your `printf` question about outputting unsigned values, you want the `u` modifier (for "unsigned"). In this case, as Jens points out below, you want `%hu`:

```
printf("a: %hu\n", a);
```

...although just `%u` (`unsigned int`, rather than `unsigned short`) would probably work as well, because the `short` will get promoted to `int` when it gets pushed on the stack for `printf`.

But again, that's only if the value 70000 will fit in an `unsigned short` on your platform.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks. Is the `h` specifier defined in a C standard? (Not C++, not a specific compiler.) My recollection (which is rusty!) is that `short` values get converted to `int` when pushed onto the stack in a varargs situation like `printf`. Edit: I get the expected output (`42, 60000, 42`) from this, for instance: http://pastie.org/1613793 `gcc -Wall` didn't give me any warnings (GCC 4.4.3). But of course, that could just be something, somewhere helping me out, could be specific to my architecture or compiler, etc., etc. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is C99. And yes, the argument is promoted to `int` if `unsigned short` fits into it, otherwise `unsigned int`. But this is just a different thing, the format specifier tells `printf` how to interpret that `int` that it receives.